# What is a sure fire way to find all files and/or path that contains 2 keywords?

Tags: bash, find, grep, ls

I was doing a

```
find . -iname '*sitesearch*' | grep demo
```

because I know the file should be `some/path/SiteSearch/demo/SiteSearch.html`, but it turned out a person put the file in as `some/path/SiteSearch/demo/index.html`, so the file cannot be found.

Is there a better way to do the search?

Such as for this case, if I do

```
find . -iname '*demo*' | grep -i sitesearch
```

it would have found it.  But I don't want to always THINK what possibility it is and figure out what pattern to use.  I just want a way that whenever the file and path have both of these 2 keywords, then print it out.  For example, if there is a way to `ls` all files will the full path on each line, then we can do

```
ls --some-flags | grep -i demo | grep -i sitesearch
```

or maybe another way / better way.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine two patterns (or more generally multiple criteria) in `find`.

```
find . -ipath '*sitesearch*' -ipath '*demo*'
```

or if you prefer regex syntax

```
find . -iregex '.*sitesearch.*' -iregex '.*demo.*'
```

“`ls` with the full path on each line” (plus traversing directories recursively, which is evidently needed here) would be `find`. While you can run `find | grep -i demo | grep -i sitesearch`, doing it all with `find` is likely to be visibly faster.

If you do this a lot, you can make it a function (put it in your `~/.kshrc` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`):

```
findallof () {
  typeset -a pred
  pred=(.)
  typeset x
  for x do
    pred=("${pred[@]}" -ipath "*$x*")
  done
  find "${pred[@]}"
}
```

Note also that you can search for files by name with [`locate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) (check the man page on your system as there are several implementations even on Linux).

```
locate -i sitesearch | grep -i demo
```

This can be faster than looking through a large directory tree, because `locate` queries an index (though case-insensitive searches tend not to be that fast). However, the index is typically rebuilt only every night, so it won't show files created today. Files that are not in a publicly readable directory may or may not be indexed depending on the implementation (check if `/usr/bin/locate` is a setuid root binary: if it is, private files are indexed and the `locate` command shows you only the files you can access).

Comment: Needs `-ipath` instead of `-iname` or it won't find `some/path/SiteSearch/demo/index.html` like grep would. Also a missing `*` after demo.

Comment: later on, I found that `find . | grep -i demo | grep -i sitesearch` should do the job too.  But your solution is just one command so it should be nicer.  Do you know how to make it into functions so that we can just say `find1 sitesearch` or `find2 demo sitesearch` or if better we don't need to say `find1` or `find2` but just `findallof`

Comment: @動靜能量 You can make it a function (see my edit).

Comment: this function doesn't work on a Mac... do you have a version that might work on both the Mac and Linux?

Comment: @動靜能量 With `.` after `find`? GNU find doesn't need it, but I think BSD find does.

Comment: If I use `findallof word1 word2`, it will say `find: ftsopen: No such file or directory`

Comment: @動靜能量 Ah, that was a bug in my code (it was passing an extra empty argument to `find`). Sorry about that. See my updated answer.